# salesforcemobilesdk-ios: How to get the userid from UserInfo class in iOS app development?

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, ios

I have created an ios app which integrated with salesforce mobile sdk. When I run the application It is displaying login view controller. I have no idea where is the code for that login view controller. Now I want to get the id of the user who gets loggedin

> i.e userId

from

> UserInfo(Apex class)

. Please help me in solving. If any further clarifications required on this question please post a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes @Ramcharan

```
let userId = SFUserAccountManager.sharedInstance().activeUserIdentity.userId
```

the variable contains string value.